# Converting PDF to Image using GhostScript with clickable hyperlinks

Tags: ghostscript

I am converting PDF to image using GhostScript. The problem i am facing is when pdf has links then i need to have those clickable links in converted image as well. How could i achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

How do you expect an image format to have 'clickable links' ? What image format do you think has the ability to click on links ?

Comment: I am using Area map to do the task but as per my calculation its hovering to wrong text. Not the actual link. You can see this in my code below for reference.

https://pastebin.com/jcGRNTmP

Comment: I still don't see what it is you are asking for, and a random sequence of XML doesn't help. Image formats can't contain hyperlinks so I don't see how you expect Ghostscript to produce an image 'with clickable links'.

Comment: Forget about what i am sharing. Simple question is I have to preserve clickable links in image while converting PDF to image using ghostscript. How to do that.? Means how to calculate link area to map the area in image.

Comment: check this post as well.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10591874/render-pdf-as-image-and-extracting-hyperlinks

Comment: Reading (very much) between the lines, it seems what you are asking for is **2** things; firstly to render a PDF file to an image, and secondly to (in some undefined manner) extract from that same PDF, the location of hyperlink annotations in the original PDF file. The post you point to above seems to me to have all the relevant information already.

Comment: But this post doesn't have the required solution

Comment: It contains all the information to create a solution as far as I can see.