# Extracting PDF annotations/comments

Tags: java, python, pdf

We have a pretty complex print workflow where the controlling is adding comments and annotations for draft versions of generated PDF documents using Adobe Reader or Adobe Acrobat. As part of the workflow imported PDF documents with annotations and comments should be parsed and the annotations should be imported into a CMS system (together with the PDF).

Q: are there any reliable tools (preferred Python or Java) for extracting such data in
clean and reliable way to PDF files?

Comment: Can you put a link to an sample pdf that contains a annotation and a comment, so we can work on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code should do the job. [One of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12502560/1699750) to the question [Parse annotations from a pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1106098/1699750) was very helpful in getting me to write the code below. It uses the poppler library to parse the annotations. This is a link to [annotations.pdf](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/25840964/stackoverflow/annotations.pdf).

**code**

```
import poppler, os.path

path = 'file://%s' % os.path.realpath('annotations.pdf')
doc = poppler.document_new_from_file(path, None)
pages = [doc.get_page(i) for i in range(doc.get_n_pages())]

for page_no, page in enumerate(pages):
    items = [i.annot.get_contents() for i in page.get_annot_mapping()]
    items = [i for i in items if i]
    print "page: %s comments: %s " % (page_no + 1, items)
```

**output**

```
page: 1 comments: ['This is an annotation'] 
page: 2 comments: [' Please note ', ' Please note ', 'This is a comment in the text']
```

**installation**

On Ubuntu the installation as as follows.

```
apt-get install python-poppler
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need but I'm having a huge amount of trouble installing poppler.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated - I've just put a question on it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32176950/install-poppler-for-python-on-mac)

Comment: @simmons I've put the installation instructions for Ubuntu. I wasn't able to install it via pip

Comment: You need `libpoppler-cpp-dev` on Ubuntu before you run `pip install python-poppler`.

Comment: After installing python-poppler, I get `AttributeError: module 'poppler' has no attribute 'document_new_from_file'`

Comment: I get `E: Unable to locate package python-poppler` when I run the apt-get command