# Install Poppler for Python on Mac

Tags: python, macos, poppler

I need to extract pdf annotations in Python.  All my searches indicate I need Poppler to do this e.g. to run [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748242/extracting-pdf-annotations-comments)

But I am having a lot of trouble installing Poppler.  I'm using Python 3.4 on OS X (Yosemite).  Here's what I've tried so far:
1. pip

```
pip3 install python-poppler-qt4
```

which gives

```
ImportError: No module named 'sipdistutils'
```

2. Next I tried

```
pip3 install pypoppler
```

And got

```
NameError: name 'file' is not defined
```

3. Next I tried downloading from [here](https://github.com/wbsoft/python-poppler-qt4)
Same error as 1.  I searched for sipdistutils and found [this](https://github.com/ifwe/sip/blob/master/sipdistutils.py) which I thought might be it.  I copied it to the folder and tried pip again.  This time I got

```
File "/python-poppler-qt4-0.24.0/sipdistutils.py", line 32
raise RuntimeError, "cannot parse SIP-generated '%s'" % sbf
```

4.  Next I tried downloading from [here](https://launchpad.net/poppler-python) and building using ./configure, which gave:

```
checking for PYPOPPLER... configure: error: Package requirements (                          pygtk-2.0 >= 2.10.0,
                     atk >= 1.6.0,
                     poppler-glib >= 0.12
                     ) were not met:

No package 'pygtk-2.0' found
No package 'atk' found
No package 'poppler-glib' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you 
installed software in a non-standard prefix.
```

5. Macports

```
sudo port install py34-poppler-qt4

Error: Failed to install poppler
Please see the log file for port poppler for details:
        /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_graphics_poppler/poppler/main.log
```

Error: The following dependencies were not installed: poppler-qt4-mac poppler qt4-mac dbus libmng lcms py34-pyqt4 dbus-python34 dbus-glib python34 python3_select py34-sip

I feel I am very close with several of these approaches - and that something very small would sort this out.

Comment: [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) (which for me has always worked much better than Macports) has a recipe for Poppler.

Comment: http://macappstore.org/poppler/

Answer (score 26):

The following still works (October 2019)

```
brew install poppler
```

Answer (score 2):

Installing Homebrew and pasting the receipe for poppler in terminal worked for me. OS-x sierra

Answer (score 1):

### Short Answer

Use conda:

```sh
conda install poppler
```

### Longer Answer

In my experience, `conda` is the best solution for installing Python packages which have external (non-Python) dependencies. There are two options for installing conda, either the full Anaconda distribution or the minimalist Miniconda utility. I prefer Miniconda, which can be installed by running a Bash script, found here:

[Miniconda Mac OSX Installers](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html#macosx-installers)

After installing Miniconda, you typically [create a new environment](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands) and then activate it, e.g.:

```sh
conda create --name py37 python=3.7
conda activate py37
```

Then you can install packages within the active Conda environment using `conda` e.g. to install `poppler`:

```sh
conda install poppler
```

You can also install packages using `pip`, e.g. to install `pdftotext` - a package which depends on `poppler`:

```sh
pip install pdftotext
```

Comment: `conda install poppler` completes normally on my WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 as if it had succeeded. But then I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'poppler'` when I try to `import poppler`

Answer (score 0):

Installing in pycharm/setting/interpreter/available packages works for me(2021-08), so maybe installing in Anaconda package management also works, but I didn't try the latter one.

Comment: If you aren't sure that you're answer will work then you shouldn't submit it.