# Trouble Installing Poppler on MacOS using Homebrew

Tags: python, homebrew, poppler

Searching for a means to extract annotations from PDFs led me to several posts using python and poppler. 

[Extracting PDF annotations/comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748242/extracting-pdf-annotations-comments)
[Parse annotations from a pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106098/parse-annotations-from-a-pdf)

However, despite encouragement that homebrew would be the answer: 
[Install Poppler for Python on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32176950/install-poppler-for-python-on-mac?newreg=6a78a7df69b64fe8bbdb7674169bb747) **see comment**

I am running into similar problems as described here:
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/12895

I have also tried using pip to install pypoppler, but have been unable, despite use of sudo and sudo -H.
(Error prompt describes issues with pycairo. Very uninterested in chasing down dependencies)

```
$ python script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pdf_annotations.py", line 1, in <module>
import poppler
ImportError: No module named poppler

$ brew search popp
==> Formulae
poppler ✔

$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip

$ python --version
Python 2.7.15
$ pip --version
pip 18.0 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

Comment: Please run `which python` and `which pip` and then edit your question and paste in the output. Thank you.

Comment: gladly!   also, i am fairly certain that my python3 & pip3 installations are not competing with 2.7 installations.

Answer (score 1):

```
brew install poppler
```

Works ok with Mojave. Also, I'd recommend using python 3.