# Poppler in path for pdf2image

Tags: python-3.x, path, poppler

I'm trying to use pdf2image and it seems I need something called `poppler` :

```
(sum_env) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\projects\summarizer>python ocr.py -i fr13_idf.pdf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\projects\summarizer\sum_env\lib\site-packages\pdf2image\pdf2image.py", line 165, in __page_count
    proc = Popen(["pdfinfo", pdf_path], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 769, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1172, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ocr.py", line 53, in <module>
    pdfspliterimager(image_path)
  File "ocr.py", line 32, in pdfspliterimager
    pages = convert_from_path("document-page%s.pdf" % i, 500)
  File "c:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\projects\summarizer\sum_env\lib\site-packages\pdf2image\pdf2image.py", line 30, in convert_from_path
    page_count = __page_count(pdf_path, userpw)
  File "c:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\projects\summarizer\sum_env\lib\site-packages\pdf2image\pdf2image.py", line 169, in __page_count
    raise Exception('Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?')
Exception: Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?
```

I tried [this link](https://github.com/QISKit/qiskit-terra/issues/586) but it the thing to download didn't solved my problem.

Comment: Iggy, I have noticed that many other people are having similar issues with Poppler on Windows. So, I wrote a short article on how to resolve this using WSL.  You can find the article here (Poppler on Windows): https://medium.com/@matthew_earl_miller/poppler-on-windows-179af0e50150

Answer (score 78):

pdf2image is only a wrapper around [poppler](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/) (not propeller!), to use the module you need to have poppler-utils installed on your machine and in your path.

The procedure is linked in the [project's README](https://github.com/Belval/pdf2image) in the "How to install" section.

Comment: So, on linux, it is `apt-get install poppler-utils`.

Comment: I cant even install poppler

Comment: on mac, it is `brew install poppler`

Comment: And the reason why `pdf2image` could not bundle `poppler` is as bad as it gets: it would then become "infected" by `poppler`'s "viral" copyleft (GPL) [license](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/-/blob/master/COPYING)

Comment: thanks @Belval, sudo yum install poppler-utils on Amazon SageMaker Notebook

Answer (score 37):

1st of all Download **Poppler** from here [here](http://blog.alivate.com.au/poppler-windows/),Then extract it.In the code section just add **poppler_path=r'C:\Program Files\poppler-0.68.0\bin'**(for eg.) like below

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
images = convert_from_path("mypdf.pdf", 500,poppler_path=r'C:\Program Files\poppler-0.68.0\bin')
for i, image in enumerate(images):
    fname = 'image'+str(i)+'.png'
    image.save(fname, "PNG")
```

Now its done.With this trick no need to add Environmental Variables.Let me know if you have any problem.

Comment: Alternatively, you can add the poppler_path as above to your windows path environment in the system settings. Don't forget to reboot afterwards. This way, you do not need to add it to each new project.

Comment: @Rajkumar What does the number 500 refer to?

Answer (score 13):

These pdf2image and pdftotext library backend requierment is Poppler, 
so you have to install

'conda install -c conda-forge poppler '

then the error will be resolved.
and if still it won't work for you then you can follow 
http://blog.alivate.com.au/poppler-windows/ to install this library.

Comment: This is no longer maintained. Download here: https://github.com/oschwartz10612/poppler-windows

Comment: Worked for me. I use mac. Thanks !

Comment: This is all that I had to do, no need to specify path to poppler, I use a mac with conda.

Answer (score 13):

## Poppler in path for pdf2image

While working with **pdf2image** there are dependency that needs to be satisfied:

1. **Installation of pdf2image**

   pip install pdf2image
2. **Installation of python-dateutil**

   pip install python-dateutil
3. **Installation of Poppler**
4. **Specifying Poppler path in environment variable (system path)**

### **Installing Poppler on Windows**

- Go to https://github.com/oschwartz10612/poppler-windows/releases/
- Under Release 21.11.0-0 Latest v21.11.0-0
- Go to Assets 3
- Download Release-21.11.0-0.zip

### **Adding Poppler to path**

- Add Poppler installed to loaction :C:\Users\UserName\Downloads\Release-21.11.0-0.zip
- Add C:\Users\UserName\Downloads\Release-21.11.0-0.zip to system
  variable path in Environment Variable

### Specifying poppler path in code

```
pages = convert_from_path(filepath, poppler_path=r"actualpoppler_path")
```

Answer (score 9):

It is poppler which is not installed properly.
Using this you can get correct package for installation.

`sudo apt-get install poppler-utils`

Answer (score 6):

For windows; to solve `PDFInfoNotInstalledError: Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?` :

- Install `chocolatey` https://chocolatey.org/install
- then install poppler using choco:
  `choco install poppler`

Comment: In order to install Choco run the following command as Powershell Admin `Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://community.chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))`

Answer (score 3):

**In Windows**

Install the Poppler for Windows [Poppler](https://github.com/oschwartz10612/poppler-windows/releases/latest)

- 500 = Quality of JPG
- the path contains  the pdf files
- pip install pdf2img

  ```
   path = r'C:\ABC\FEF\KLH\pdf_extractor\output\break'

   def spliting_pdf2img( path):
       from pdf2image import convert_from_path, convert_from_bytes
       for file in os.listdir(path):
           if file.lower().endswith(".pdf"):
               pages = convert_from_path(os.path.join(path,file), 500,poppler_path= r'C:\ABC\DEF\Downloads\poppler-0.68.0\Library\bin')
               for page in pages:                    
                   page.save(os.path.join(path,file.lower().replace(".pdf",".jpg")),'JPEG')
  ```

**In Linux/UBUNTU**
Install the below packages in the ubuntu/linux terminal

- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install poppler-utils

  ```
  path = r'C:\ABC\FEF\KLH\pdf_extractor\output\break'

   def spliting_pdf2img( path):
       from pdf2image import convert_from_path, convert_from_bytes
       for file in os.listdir(path):
           if file.lower().endswith(".pdf"):
               pages = convert_from_path(os.path.join(path,file), 500)
               for page in pages:                    
                   page.save(os.path.join(path,file.lower().replace(".pdf",".jpg")),'JPEG')
  ```

Answer (score 3):

FOR MAC, if you have brew installed, that is the way to go.

```
brew install poppler
```

Takes several minutes to install all the dependencies, but pdf2image will work afterwards.

This is a repeat of an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32176950/install-poppler-for-python-on-mac) and the answer is also in a comment on this page. Adding this answer b/c it took me a while to find the correct solution FOR MACs.

Comment: for mac M1: 

Error: Cannot install in Homebrew on ARM processor in Intel default prefix (/usr/local)!

Comment: Yeah, I seem to remember having some M1 issues with Homebrew. Pretty common and several ways to get around. Some solutions are listed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64963370/error-cannot-install-in-homebrew-on-arm-processor-in-intel-default-prefix-usr.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone still has this error on Windows, I solved the problem by:

- Download the Latest binary of Poppler for Windows from [Poppler for Windows](https://github.com/oschwartz10612/poppler-windows/releases/latest)
- Unzip it into C drive like `C:\poppler-0.68.0`
- Specify the Poppler path like this:

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import sys
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import os

ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.curdir)

# Path of the pdf 
PDF_file = ROOT_DIR + r"\PdfToImage\src\2.pdf"
  
''' 
Part #1 : Converting PDF to images 
'''
  
# Store all the pages of the PDF in a variable 
pages = convert_from_path(PDF_file, 500, poppler_path=r'C:\poppler-0.68.0\Library\bin')
```

Comment: I followed these steps but i still get the "Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?"

Answer (score 1):

I kind of followed the steps from one of the previous posted answers except I had to add the path in env variables. Adding path in pdf2image.convert_from_path didn't worked for me. So, if anyone still has this error on Windows, I solved the problem by:

1. Download the Latest binary of Poppler for Windows from [Poppler
   Windows](https://github.com/oschwartz10612/poppler-windows/releases/)
2. Unzip it into C drive like C:\poppler-0.68.0
3. Specify the Poppler path in environment variables

[Poppler path in env variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puJME.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a mac in Visual Studio Code and I encountered this error. I followed the install instructions and was able to verify the packages were installed but the error persisted when running in VSC.

Even though I had my `python.condaPath` and `python.pythonPath` specified in my `settings.json` it wasn't until activated the conda environment inside of the VSC integrated terminal itself

`conda activate my_env`

that the error went away..

Bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

After downloading poppler do this....
import os
os.environ["PATH"] = r"C:.....\poppler-xxxxxxx\bin"
use this to make environment hope it works.It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my Mac 
I solved it by replacing the poppler_path from - `poppler_path= '\usr\bin'`
" to `poppler_path= '\usr\local\bin'`
but you can try to print all the places that poppler might be in your mac
by  `echo $PATH`  in the Terminal and try all the options as `poppler_path=" "`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30126219)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Mac using Visual Studio Code and a conda environment.

I found out that I could run the code from the command line, however not from VS code. I then printed the environment variables when running from the command line and in VS code using:

`print(os.environ)`

When I compared the two, I noticed that the "PATH" variable was different. My conda environment was not in the "PATH" variable in VS code. I think this means that VS code was not correctly activating my conda environment. I therefore took my "PATH" from the command line and set it in my launch.json environment variables. Then the problem was fixed.

```
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "python": "/Users/<username>/miniconda3/envs/<env_name>/bin/python",
            "env": {
                "PATH":"<PATH STRING from command line>"
            },
            "program": "${file}"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Windows** user

One just need to

1. downlow the zip file from [here](https://github.com/oschwartz10612/poppler-windows/releases/)
2. Unzip it to the preferred location
3. Add the poppler_path parameter to the convert_from_path function like

   images = convert_from_path(pdf_file, poppler_path = r"C:\Users\your_path\poppler-23.11.0\Library\bin")

remember you need to add the directory of \bin folder

ref: https://pypi.org/project/pdf2image/

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS:
Nothing helped me, nothing except pass the direct path to the popler in the $PATH

The path was /opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/24.02.0/bin

I just wrote

```
import os
os.environ["PATH"] = os.getenv('PATH') + ':' + '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/poppler/24.02.0/bin'
```

Answer (score -1):

Use for linux -
conda install -c conda-forge poppler

In python code doesn't give poppler_path.For me it's work.

images = convert_from_path(pdf_path)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Once I included poppler_path and pointed as follows, it worked for me. 
`convert_from_path(pdf_path, poppler_path=r'C:\poppler-23.11.0\Library\bin')`

Answer (score -1):

FYI - if someone is looking for this. It appears that conda-forge now has Poppler binaries:

https://github.com/conda-forge/poppler-feedstock

However, you will still need to add it in path.

Another location to get binaries is this repo: https://github.com/oschwartz10612/poppler-windows

Answer (score -3):

I had same issue but I have fixed it in my django project by changing directory.
Actually first you need to store this pdf image file in side your media directory.
Then you need to change your current directory to this media directory(where this pdf image file has been stored).
This is my code snippet in django project where I have converted .pdf image to .jpg

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image

def convert_pdf_2_image(uploaded_image_path, uploaded_image,img_size):
    project_dir = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(uploaded_image_path)
    file_name = str(uploaded_image).replace('.pdf','')
    output_file = file_name+'.jpg'
    pages = convert_from_path(uploaded_image, 200)
    for page in pages:
        page.save(output_file, 'JPEG')
        break
    os.chdir(project_dir)
    img = Image.open(output_file)
    img = img.resize(img_size, PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img.save(output_file)
    return output_file
```

Comment: Your code is missing imports and still results in the poppler error message if the original reason for this error is not resolved.

Comment: Yup, `convert_from_path` is from `pdf2image` which requires GPL-licensed `poppler`. @abhay, I'd delete this answer