# Poppler PDFInfoNotInstalledError

Tags: python, poppler

Part of PDF rendering and conversion using `Poppler`, I have following code in place but executing code ended-up having error which is mentioned below.

> Error message: pdf2image.exceptions.PDFInfoNotInstalledError: Unable
>   to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?

I have added the Poppler path as environment variable but error still persist.

````
import tempfile,os
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as path:
    images_from_path = convert_from_path("C:\\Users\\mehak\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\iffco.pdf")

index = 1
for image in images_from_path:
    image.save("C:\\Users\\mehak\\OneDrive\\Desktop" + str(index) + ".jpg")
    index += 1```



```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mehak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pdf2image\pdf2image.py", line 355, in _page_count
    proc = Popen(command, env=env, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\mehak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\mehak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing_ocrpdf.py", line 7, in <module>
    images_from_path = convert_from_path('D:\\iffco.pdf')
  File "C:\Users\mehak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pdf2image\pdf2image.py", line 82, in convert_from_path
    page_count = _page_count(pdf_path, userpw, poppler_path=poppler_path)
  File "C:\Users\mehak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pdf2image\pdf2image.py", line 360, in _page_count
    "Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?"
pdf2image.exceptions.PDFInfoNotInstalledError: Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?```
````

Comment: This is very much context specific error. Where does this testing_ocrpdf.py located ? can you post complete code? Can you also check whether you installed poppler-utils ?

Comment: now i've placed the code in documents folder and mentioned the complete code above & tried installing poppler-utils but got this error:

Comment: C:\Users\mehak\Documents>pip install poppler-utils
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement poppler-utils (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for poppler-utils

Comment: To use poppler, you need to have poppler-utils installed on your machine and in your path. https://github.com/Belval/pdf2image/blob/master/README.md

Comment: i've installed "poppler-0.51" and added the same as poppler_path in env var as : "C:\Program Files\poppler-0.51_x86\poppler-0.51\bin" but getting the same errors

Comment: can you add complete source and the files.

Comment: it's done now, i added its path as "new" in "Path" already mentioned in env var, then it worked fine. No need to create new path in system variables.

Comment: That's great. Good to know. You can mark your thread as answer. So others find it helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Poppler in path for pdf2image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53481088/poppler-in-path-for-pdf2image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed these steps to include path and it works as expected.

[New or edit this variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktS8q.png) and [mention your path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrPlG.png).

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit, what exactly did you add in your path?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the solution [here](https://github.com/Belval/pdf2image).

`pip install pdf2image`

You only did the steps above.

The following step dependents on your computer system.

##### Windows

Windows users will have to build or download poppler for Windows. I recommend @oschwartz10612 version which is the most up-to-date. You will then have to add the `bin/` folder to PATH or use `poppler_path = r"C:\path\to\poppler-xx\bin" as an argument` in `convert_from_path`.

##### Mac

Mac users will have to install poppler.

Installing using Brew:

`brew install poppler`

##### Linux

Most distros ship with `pdftoppm` and `pdftocairo`. If they are not installed, refer to your package manager to install `poppler-utils`.

Platform-independant (Using `conda`)
Install poppler: `conda install -c conda-forge poppler`
Install pdf2image: `pip install pdf2image`