# Converting PDF to Image with pdf2image does not work

Tags: python, pdf

I want to convert PDF file to image file (.jpg, or .png ...). I have found this solution but I always get an error:

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path 

pages = convert_from_path('sample.pdf', 500) # I have tried with full path, and with different num of pages
```

The error that I get:

```
pdf2image.exceptions.PDFInfoNotInstalledError: Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?
```

How can I fix this?

If there is any other way to convert pdf to .jpg please let me know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Poppler in path for pdf2image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53481088/poppler-in-path-for-pdf2image)

Comment: I cant even install poppler !
Do you know, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Would you please update your question accordingly? Nobody of us has a crystal ball. ;-)

Comment: @ChristianBaumann  Please check this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64101224/convert-pdf-to-jpg-in-python-and-pass-it-to-tesseract

Answer (score 0):

**Download the Poppler method from the below link**

1. [Poppler for Windows](http://blog.alivate.com.au/poppler-windows/)
2. [How to Install poppler-utils in Ubuntu/Linux](https://www.howtoinstall.me/ubuntu/18-04/poppler-utils/)
3. `sudo apt-get install poppler-utils` sudo code for ubuntu
4. Download the Poppler package and extract it. open the Poppler folder and copy the bin folder path to `poppler_path` variable (for windows only, no need for linux)
5. If system is windows/Linux Using platform module returns a string that displays the name of the operation system on the current device being used to run the program.

   ```
   from pdf2image import convert_from_path, convert_from_bytes
   import platform

   if platform.system() == "Windows":     
       pages = convert_from_path(r"C:\ABC\xyz.pdf", 500,poppler_path= r'C:\ABC\poppler-0.68.0\bin')
   elif if platform.system() == "Linux":
       pages = convert_from_path(r"C:\ABC\xyz.pdf", 500)
   for page in pages:
       page.save(r"C:\ABC\xyz.pdf".lower().replace(".pdf",".jpg"),'JPEG')
   ```