# Extract comments from pdf

Tags: r, pdf

I have a collection of .pdf files with comments that were added in Adobe Acrobat. I would like to be able to analyze these comments, but I'm kind of stuck on extracting them. I've looked at the pdftools package, but it seems to only be able to extract the text and not the comments. Is there a method available for extracting the comments within R?

Answer (score 8):

PyMuPDF (https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is the only python library I have found working.

Installation in Debian/Ubuntu-based distributions:

```
apt-get install python3-fitz
```

Script:

```py
import fitz
doc = fitz.open("example.pdf")
for i in range(doc.pageCount):
  page = doc[i]
  for annot in page.annots():
    print(annot.info["content"])
```

Comment: BTW, people may find useful to know that to install fitz in a conda environment, you should activate the environment, then run `pip install fitz`. See https://github.com/kastman/fitz/blob/master/doc/source/installing.rst
Or, even better, `pip install pymupdf` (it installs fitz, and avoids errors like this https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/issues/523#issuecomment-830746585)

Comment: Is there a way to make fitz extract the highlighted content as well? I created a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72311956/how-to-extract-highlights-and-text-box-contents-from-pdf-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Did you try PoDoFo or another OpenSource tool that can access the PDF elements?
You can also look at [Extracting PDF annotations/comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748242/extracting-pdf-annotations-comments) on stackoverflow if you will do little programming

Comment: I've tried a few tools, but they all seem focused on extracting images and text.The Python method you linked to combined with the reticulate package looks promising and I'd actually played around with that a bit last week, but the poppler module doesn't seem to want to install. I guess there isn't a native solution in R.

Comment: I got it. Sometimes it´s hard to find working solution for such specific cases. Have you tried looking for some paid solution that would work? Some of them offer free trial. Which programming language and platform do you prefer?

Comment: My preference would be a method that imported the comments into R on Windows as a data.frame. I was finally able to get poppler working using the Linux subsystem on Windows which is less than optimal, but better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

[Screenshot of how >>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJg8P.png)   Export the comments as an Excel file, then import it into R?

Eg: in `PDF-X-change Editor`, go to `comment > summarize comments > export` into whatever format you want. Similar in Adobe.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can consider calling the Python package from **R** as follows :

```
library(reticulate)

conda_Env <- conda_list()

if(any(conda_Env[, 1] == "PyMuPDF") == FALSE)
{
  reticulate::conda_create(envname = "PyMuPDF", python_version = "3.7.16")
  reticulate::conda_install(envname = "PyMuPDF", packages = "PyMuPDF", pip = TRUE)
}

reticulate::use_condaenv(condaenv = "PyMuPDF")
path_To_PDF <- "C:/Annotated text.pdf"
fitz <- import("fitz")
doc <- fitz$open(path_To_PDF)
nb_Page <- doc$page_count
list_Comments <- list()
list_Highlights <- list()

##########################
#### Highlighted text ####
##########################
for(i in 1 : nb_Page)
{
  page <- doc[i - 1]
  annots <- page$annots()
  list_Highlights[[i]] <- page$get_textbox(iter_next(annots)$rect)
}

########################
#### Commented text ####
########################
counter <- 1

for(i in 1 : nb_Page)
{
  page <- doc[i - 1]
  annots <- page$annots()
  cond <- TRUE

  while(cond == TRUE)
  {
    content <- iter_next(annots)$info$content
    cond <- !is.null(content)
    list_Comments[[counter]] <- content
    counter <- counter + 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to extract the comments of a PDF file with Ghostscript and **R**. First, I convert the PDF file with Ghostscript. This generates markers in the PDF file when you read the PDF file as a txt file. Afterwards, I read the pdf file as a txt file and extract the comments with a regex.

```
library(stringr)
system2("C:\\Program Files\\gs\\gs10.02.0\\bin\\gswin64c.exe",args="-sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dDOPDFMARKS -dNOPAUSE -dPreserveAnnots=true -dBATCH -o C:\\Annotated_F.pdf C:\\Annotated.pdf")
fileConn <- file("C:\\Users\\manuh\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Test\\Annotated_F.pdf")
txt <- readLines(fileConn)
bool_Txt <- stringr::str_detect(txt, "/Contents\\(")
txt_Comments <- txt[bool_Txt]
txt_Comments <- stringr::str_remove(txt_Comments, "/Contents\\(")
nb_Char <- nchar(txt_Comments)
txt_Comments <- stringr::str_sub(txt_Comments, end = nb_Char - 1)
txt_Comments

[1] "Commentaires 1" "Commentaire 2"
```

The PDF files used in the example are available here : https://github.com/ManuHamel/R_Examples_PDF_Annotation