# Installing a package inside Conda using apt install

Tags: python, opencv, installation, conda, apt-get

I'm trying to install opencv in my Jetson TX2. I would like to install it within my conda environment. I used the following command to do so,

```
sudo apt-get install python-opencv
```

It actually installs opencv but outside the conda so I'm not able to import it within  conda. How can I have it installed within my conda?.

Comment: I run into the same problem trying to install `fitz` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50801270/extract-comments-from-pdf). Did you find the answer?

Answer (score 4):

maybe not exactly the answer but might be what most people missing.

- `apt install`s for system-wide package install. So this is available in all conda environments
- `conda install`s package in conda environment. So package is visible in specific conda environment you installed

Comment: Not everything available in `apt-get install` is available in `conda install`. This is not a good answer.

Comment: Yes, I agree, not everything available in apt is available in conda for installation. Thanks for that knowledge. However, I don't see  how this knowledge relates to my answer. would you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: The title of the question is "Installing a package inside Conda using apt install". Your answer doesn't answer that. It just finds another way to install the package the OP wants. I came to the question searching for a way to install a package that is not available in `conda install`. I'm probably not alone.

Comment: I agree. In fact, none of the answers have a solution to the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are in a conda environment.

Run a conda command, instead of an apt-get command.

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

Comment: conda forge does not have the build for arm device like Jetson :(

Answer (score 0):

You can just install pip in the conda environment and install opencv using pip.

```
conda install pip
pip install opencv-python
```