# How to extract highlights and text box contents from pdf in python?

Tags: python, pdf

I would like to use python to extract highlights, text box and text box color from PDFs.

I am having trouble installing `poppler`, mentioned in the related question [Extracting PDF annotations/comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748242/extracting-pdf-annotations-comments)

And I couldn't find how to make the `fitz` package extract highlighted text (https://stackoverflow.com/a/61761129/1273751) from a pdf with highlights on pg 3, 4, and 14. And text boxes on pg 4 and 14.

```py
import fitz
doc = fitz.open("example.pdf")
for i in range(doc.pageCount):
    page = doc[i]
    for annot in page.annots():
        print(i, "||", annot.info["content"], "||", annot.colors, "||", annot.type)
```

Output was:

```html
3 ||  || {'stroke': [0.4156799912452698, 0.8509830236434937, 0.15685999393463135], 'fill': []} || (8, 'Highlight')
4 ||  || {'stroke': [0.9843140244483948, 0.5333399772644043, 1.0], 'fill': []} || (8, 'Highlight')                                                                                                                                       
4 ||  || {'stroke': [0.4156799912452698, 0.8509830236434937, 0.15685999393463135], 'fill': []} || (8, 'Highlight')                                                                                                                           
4 ||  || {'stroke': [1.0, 0.8196110129356384, 0.0], 'fill': []} || (8, 'Highlight')                                                           
4 || how does it allow that? || {'stroke': [0.9882349967956543, 0.9568629860877991, 0.5215759873390198], 'fill': []} || (2, 'FreeText')                                                                                                      
14 || what's ensemble accuracy? || {'stroke': [0.9882349967956543, 0.9568629860877991, 0.5215759873390198], 'fill': []} || (2, 'FreeText')                                                                                                   
14 ||  || {'stroke': [1.0, 0.8196110129356384, 0.0], 'fill': []} || (8, 'Highlight')
```

For the highlights, it gives me the color of the highlight, but not the actual text that was highlighted.

It works well for the text box, though.

**Answer to another related question**:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65631205/1273751

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like that has nicely extracted highlights and highlight text.  Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: I edited it to become clearer about what is missing: the text content of what was highlighted

Answer (score 0):

With fitz, I managed to extract text box contents.

And now I have found an answer using fitz to extract the highlighted text content
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63686095/1273751

(I have not tested it)

Comment: Given that the linked SO question/answer answers your question, do you see any value in leaving your question and answer up?  That is does you Q/A _add_ something that doesn't exist in the other Q/A?

Comment: It's debatable. But I believe having the outputs that I put in my question is useful. And also that I am talking here about both highlights and text boxes. I would leave it, but I can be convinced otherwise. Not sure how to reason about what to do in this case. What do you think? The alternative would be just deleting? Mark as duplicate? What is it?