# How does python extracts the page with annotations from a PDF?

Tags: python, pdf, extract, pypdf

Have some PDF files containing annotation in random pages.

All I want to do is recognizing the page with annotations and pack those pages in a new PDF file.
(What I mean annotation is just some straight or could lines draw by Adobe acrobat pdf reader)

**How do I use pypdf to recognize if a page has annotations?**

I use Python 2.7 on MAC and have already installed pypdf.
Is this even possible with pypdf?

Answer (score 1):

Try poppler. Here is an answer where the author parsed annotations from the PDF document using python-poppler: [Parse annotations from a pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106098/parse-annotations-from-a-pdf)

Comment: I've noticed that post and poppler before, but I thought there would be something more handy. Okay I'm trying to go through poppler first. Thanks any way.