# Using poppler to extract annotations. g_free() / get_color() issue

Tags: python, pdf, annotations, poppler

I borrowed this python code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106098/parse-annotations-from-a-pdf) (first answer by enno groper) to automate the extraction of annotations from pdfs.

I want to make some modifications to the code. Trying to fetch the color of annotations with `annot_mapping.annot.get_color()` I ran into the first issue. What the command returns is objects like this one `<PopplerColor at 0x1a85180>`, rather than rgb values ([promised here](https://people.freedesktop.org/~ajohnson/docs/poppler-glib/poppler-PopplerColor.html#PopplerColor)).

According to [poppler docs](https://people.freedesktop.org/~ajohnson/docs/poppler-glib/PopplerAnnot.html#poppler-annot-get-color) `poppler_annot_get_color()` returns "a new allocated PopplerColor with the color values of poppler_annot , or NULL. It must be freed with g_free() when done".

Is this correct and if yes, how do I achieve this in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`annot_mapping.annot.get_color()` gives you a PopplerColor, which is a structure with three members (of type guint16): red, green, and blue. For example:

```
PopplerColor *color = poppler_annot_get_color (annot);
g_printf ("%d\n", color->red);
```

gives you the red value of your annotation `annot`, the gb values can be obtained similarly.

In python this is achieved through `annot_mapping.annot.get_color().red`, assuming you have `import poppler`