# how to install poppler for python 3 in linux?

Tags: linux, python-3.x, poppler

Is there a way to install poppler for python 3 in linux?

I have used `apt-get install python-poppler` to install it for python 2, but I haven't found how to do it for python 3.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 trusty

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: I have Ubuntu 14.04 trusty

Comment: Would you be fine with using `pip` for installation?

Comment: I would love to use pip (pip3?) for installation

Comment: I ran into a problem while trying to use `pip` to install though. I will write an answer later if I can figure out how to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu 16.04 you can install the package `python3-poppler-qt4` or `python3-poppler-qt5`, e.g.,:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-poppler-qt4
```

`python3-poppler-qt5` does not appear to be available on releases prior to Xenial, and `python3-poppler-qt4` can be installed this way on [16.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=python3-poppler) or [15.10](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=wily&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=python3-poppler), but not earlier.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have Ubuntu 14.04 trusty. So apparently this solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: @PabloGuerrero This is why you should always specify in your question what Linux distribution you are using.